# C# : Implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'bool'

Tags: c#

I got a weird error message when I tried to convert an `object` to `bool`, here is my code:

```
public partial class ModifierAuteur : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public ModifierAuteur(object getKeyDecesCheckBox)
    {
         decesCheckBox.Checked = getKeyDecesCheckBox == null ? null : (bool)getKeyDecesCheckBox;
    }
}
```

and this is the error message :

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between `<null>` and `bool`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming that the assignment is possible, you need to convert to a nullable `bool`, like this:

```
decesCheckBox.Checked = getKeyDecesCheckBox == null ? null : (bool?)((bool)getKeyDecesCheckBox);
```

The inner cast to `bool` unboxes the value, and the outer cast to `bool?` makes it compatible with `null` of the conditional expression.

If the left-hand side of the assignment does not allow `null`s, you need to decide on the value to set when `getKeyDecesCheckBox` is `null`. Usually, that's a `false`:

```
 decesCheckBox.Checked = getKeyDecesCheckBox == null ? false : (bool)getKeyDecesCheckBox;
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say this didn't work, this is the error message :

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @user1726655 Ah, but then your left-hand side does not allow `null`s, you need to change `null` for `false` (or `true` if sending `null` means the item must be checked, though I doubt it). I made an edit to the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the Checked property is of type nullable bool, I would probably do the following:

```
decesCheckBox.Checked = (getKeyDecesCheckBox == null ? (bool?)null : (bool?)getKeyDecesCheckBox);
```

If it takes a bool (not-nullable) you can convert the null to false easily with:

```
decesCheckBox.Checked = (getKeyDecesCheckBox == null ? (bool?)null : (bool?)getKeyDecesCheckBox).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

`decesCheckBox.Checked` is of type `bool`. As such you must feed it either `false` or `true`.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please see the comments to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Your '? :' operator has two possible incompatible return types: if the object is null, then it returns the value null, which can be cast to any nullable type. If the object is not null, then its return type is bool.

I don't know what type 'Checked' is, but I suspect that its type is 'bool'.

The problem here is that you can't cast null to the 'bool' type, and so you have to decide what type you want it to be in the case the object is null. If you wanted it to be false, you could write the statement as:

```
decesCheckBox.Checked = (getKeyDecesCheckBox as bool) ?? false;
```

The ?? Operator assigns the value 'false' in the case where the object is null, or cannot be converted to a bool.

Comment: That won't work. The `as` operator can't be used with a structure type, and `bool` is.